# Variables in alias

Tags: bash, variables, alias

I want to set up variable in alias command so it would be like this:

```
alias "mycommand $variable"="command1 -y ppp $variable.mp3 -i rrr - | command2 --text $variable --ssss -"
```

Comment: you mean this all "--sssss" or something like that?

Comment: ...in general, aliases are the less-capable, less-useful little brother to shell functions -- they're just simple string prefix substitutions, so they can't do conditional logic based on parameters, they can't take arguments in anything but the last position, etc. If you want to do anything serious, you should be using a function instead.

Answer (score 7):

Use a function instead.

```
mycommand() {
  command1 -y ppp "${1}.mp3" -i rrr - | command2 --text "$1" --ssss -
}
```

If you wanted to pass *all* arguments through rather than only the first one, you'd use `"$@"` instead of `"$1"`.